# Elementor forcing display:none on my custom scrollbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having an issue with this code, it works fine on a fresh website but when I try to place it within the themes additional css the scrollbar does not appear.
When I looked at the console the issue I see that above the code `display:none;` shows up.
I also tried to use custom css and JS plugin to load it before elementor.

Theme:astra
Builder:Elementor
Url:[www.dizzidesign.com](http://www.dizzidesign.com)

```
<style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.9vw !important;
  background: #F4A44D !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, #FF4ED9) !important;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #FF4ED9) !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}

.custom-blend-mode {
  mix-blend-mode: difference !important;
}

</style>
```